# Override request for pagination for first page

Tags: java

I have this code which calculates pages based on sent range:

```
private Pair<Integer, Integer> parse(String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            return Pair.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        int start = 0;
        int end = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(value);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            start = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            end = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            if (start < 1 || end < start) {
                throw new InvalidRangePatternException(value);
            }
        }

        if (start == 0) {
            return Pair.of(start, end);
        }

        int size = end - start;
        int page = start / size;

        return Pair.of(page, size);
    }
```

The code works when I send range 0-10, 10-20, 20-35 to display data. But there is one requirement to have 1 always as a first starting number. 0 can't be used.
Do you know how I can intercept `range` value at the beginning of the method and override it with 1 without breaking the logic.

Comment: Do you mean changing the range from 0 - 10 to 1 - 11?  If so, just add one.

Comment: I mean when I receive 1-10 to change it to 1-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but at the end, why do you divide `start` with `size`?
I think

```
int page = start % size
```

would be more suitable. again, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: in short Angular sends request to get page elements 1-10. Spring BE should translate this to 0-10. Got the idea?